# Two col-md-6 not work with responsive

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Left is col-md-6 is tekst with font size 50px; and right is responsive picture col-md-6. Text is not responsive.Text can not be adapted to the size of the screen How to fix it.

```
<div id="prvideo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <p><em>AKTUELNOSTI U VOĆARSTVU DANAS</em> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="malina">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to be more specific or add some code

Comment: You will probably have to change your font-size at certain breakpoints

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some of the points here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You're missing the `row` container in your code. I also switched to smaller breakpoints so it shows up correctly in the demo

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="prvideo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p><em>AKTUELNOSTI U VOĆARSTVU DANAS</em></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="malina">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: work on 420x800 but not work on 320480 col-xs-12 col-sm-6

Comment: @dejan Could you share more of what your code looks like?

Comment: <div id="prvideo">
    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <p><em>AKTUELNOSTI U VOĆARSTVU DANAS</em>
                        </p>
     </div> 
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                     <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="malina">
                    </div>    
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: I solved the problem so that I reduce the font 50xp to 25px, thanks

Comment: Thanks!!! you saved me so much time